# A tag created 9 hours ago has 1 question and 3k followers?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, tags

I found this tag [visual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual) which was created 9 hours ago from the date of asking and has no description whatsoever. But surprisingly on hovering over the tag shows that the tag has 3k followers.

Is it really the case or some wrong matching and counting behind that caused this? Is it sort of a bug?

**More details**

**Image 1**

[image: Image 1]

**Image 2**

[image: Image 2]

On seeing the tag info, it was mentioned that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46517480/is-standard-c-signal-h-buggy-on-visual-2008) question led to the creation of this tag, but the question did not have that tag as well! I then checked whether the tag is just a synonym of a highly followed existing tag from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all), but didn't find this tag there as well.

Comment: Possibly 3000 people have `[visual*]` as a favourite tag, so any new tag matching the pattern would automatically have a bunch of followers.

Comment: _but the question did not have that tag as well!_ It was [edited out](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46517480/3). I dont see a bug here

Comment: @Stijn So does that mean angular2 or related tags which came after angularjs will display followers of angularjs as well as all who follows [angular *]?

Comment: @KaranDesai [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular*). You are essentially following all tags beginning with angular if you follow angular*

Comment: @Stijn thanks for the tip about the `*`, didn't heard of it before, it allowed me to clean my favorite tags list.

Comment: I still am confused. I didn't use [visual *] in search term, I simply hovered on [Visual] tag. Does the code behind it uses [visual *] to count followers?

Comment: I retagged this question with [visual-studio]